Can I use a texture to change the strength of a shape key on an object being used as a particle?
I want to make it so that the object I'm using as a particle changes shape throughout its lifetime. However, it doesn't seem like I can change the shape key strength from the emitter object. I do not want to manually keyframe the shape change.

You can attract more attention if you can provide more details of what you currently have tried and where you got stuck at. Some screenshots and elaborate more on the details of the issue.
